# Overwrite file without truncating it

Tags: dd

I'm basically looking for a `dd if=inputfile of=outputfile conv=notrunc,nocreat` alternative. I need it because simply overwriting files may severely increase fragmentation, so replacing them in place solves this problem completely.

Here's why I need an alternative:

1. I suspect that dd might not be the fastest way to overwrite large files because it uses the buffer.

The way I understand how it works:

- It reads a block of data from the input file (this takes time)
- It then writes this block to the output file (the input file meanwhile is not being read, i.e. time is being wasted)

2. The other issue is that `dd` is quite cumbersome to use, i.e. when I want to copy several files it requires bash scripting instead of `command file1 file2 file3 /destination`.

Comment: I am probably missing something very obvious here, I don't really know anything about filesystems, and haven't run a `dd` command in many, many years, but wouldn't a simple `mv inputfile outputfile` be better?

Comment: @terdon I need to back up large files *across* different disk drives. Those files always have the same length but their contents change, thus I cannot use `cp` or `mv` as it will lead to insane fragmentation. Files are tens of gigabytes in size. Currently I use the above `dd` command to "copy" them but it's all a little bit cumbersome.

Comment: Regarding point 1, I cannot tell if that would influence performances but you can prevent read and/or write thanks to iflag/oflag=direct. For what concerns dd performances due to lack of parallelization, did you try using sg3_utils' sgp_dd utility ? (I can't tell about their potential to increase fragmentation though)